# Local Host call vs Azure App Service call (Slow in Azure)

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a service running in azure (in the same service plan as other services).

When this service runs locally (with the exact same settings as the one in azure), my service endpoint returns within 2 seconds. However when it runs in Azure it takes up to a minute.

The service endpoint itself is calling a bunch of external apis.

Looking at app insights it seems like the external api's is taking forever to return. (~10s a piece). Hitting the same external endpoints manually confirms that it returns immediately. AppInsights also shows that the services only takes 6.8ms doing work, but then spends the rest of the time waiting.

[image]

My intuition says its some form of connection starvation where the Azure app is waiting for a thread or connection to become available but checking the Azure metrics shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: What App Service Plan is involved?

Comment: We are running on a P1. Not sure what you are asking. All the apps involved are on the same app service plan.

Comment: One way to test your theory is to shut down other app services running on the ASP and give it a few mins before you test the service under investigation. Off course this may not be an option if this is your production ASP. This is to test if other apps in the same ASP are starving of resources for the service under test.

How does the ASP metrics like CPU and memory looks like?

Comment: Or move the app in question to a different app service plan temporarily while debugging.

Comment: I've done a restart of the app service earlier today. It had no effect. So unless its grabbing the resources on start up I'm stumped

Comment: @JacquesBosch sure ... I unfortunately don't have that much control over our hosting env.

Comment: PS CPU, memory, connections all seem reasonable.

Comment: >I've done a restart of the app service earlier today. It had no effect. So unless its grabbing the resources on start up I'm stumped – Murdock 3 mins ago

The suggestion by @HariSubramaniam is to rule out the possibility of other apps causing your problem.

Comment: Sure. But the app service plan was restarted with no better results.

Comment: >Sure. But the app service plan was restarted with no better results. – Murdock 8 mins ago
I don't know of a way that an app service plan can be restarted, other than having it as a side effect of scaling vertically.

Comment: Yes we scaled the service plan.

Comment: Is the distance difference between the region of Azure servers where to your app is hosted and your computer when running the app locally large enough to cause a problem?

Comment: The dependencies and the slow app are in the same region, so imo my local should be slower.